# Most bizarre/easiest to fly X-Plane aircraft?

Tags: flight-simulator

I’m currently trying to get my little brother into flight sims. When we were little, we got to crash planes on our grandfather’s computer, which has kind of gotten us both into flying (…kind of ironically?). I’ve gotten pretty good at the basics, but I want to get him into it, because his current hobby is endlessly listening to Harry Potter audiobooks, which gets annoying after the third play through. He will get bored after a while if he doesn’t laugh hard enough, so I wanted to ask the community about aircraft.

My questions are: **what are the easiest aircraft to fly in X-Plane?** and **What are the most bizarre/funniest aircraft to fly in X-Plane?**

As sort of a side question, what are some other ways to make him interested in flying using better strategies? (Keep in mind, he’s only just turning eleven next month.)

*…maybe i should try crashing planes again. nostalgia.*

Mods, feel free to delete this question if it’s too off-topic! :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about PC flight simulation without a relation to real world aviation. See also [The scope of Flight Simulation questions on the Aviation SE](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/the-scope-of-flight-simulation-questions-on-the-aviation-se) on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

For default aircraft in XPlane 11, I would start with the tried and true Cessna 172SP.  I would avoid using the Stinson L5 as a starting Aircraft as it is very difficult to control on the ground (a sim model fault not found in the characteristics of the real thing) and he will probably have a devil of a time landing it without causing a ground loop.

Your comment about crashing the airplane reminds me of my childhood playing the original monochromatic Microsoft flight simulator. A neighborhood friend of mine and I would take turns taking off from Chicago Lakefront Airport (the now defunct Meigs field) and crashing the airplane into the Sears Tower and thought it was the funniest thing to do.  This was 1983, mind you, when life was much simpler and we had no idea that our harmless simulated havoc was going to become a tragic reality some 18 years later on Sept 11, 2001.